# m2m relations are not displayed or saved in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, m2m

```
class A(Model):
    to_b = ManyToManyField('B', blank=True, through='AtoB')

class B(Model):
    to_a = ManyToManyField('A', blank=True, through='AtoB')

class AtoB(Model):
    a =  ForeignKey('A', on_delete=CASCADE)
    b =  ForeignKey('B', on_delete=CASCADE)
    usr =  ForeignKey(settings.USER, on_delete=CASCADE)
    # some other fields
```

Im making a django application.
This is roughly equivalent to what i have in my models.py
I need m2m relation between A and B to go through another model because i need to store additional data there.
Now there is a problem - when i try to save instance of model **A** in my custom view, relations with **B** instances are not saved no matter whether i pick them or not.
And when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin and try to create instance of **A** from there, i dont even see proper field (should be `<select multiple>` i guess) for selecting relations with **B**.
Can someone please explain me why relations are not saved, and not even displayed in /admin?
Here is code roughly equivalent to what i have in views.py:

```
class Create(CreateView):
    model = None  # A or B
    template_name = 'something.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

in urls.py i specify additional arguments like this:
`views.Create.as_view(model=models.A, fields=['to_b'])`

Comment: Please share the piece of code where you try to create this relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not going to work. If you are using your own ManytoMany intermediary table, you have to manually manage and save the objects yourself. Using Django's builtin functions won't work.

Save `Object A`, then save `Object B` and then save the relation in your `AtoB` table (which is also an object).

```
a_to_b = AtoB.objects.create(a=object_a, b=object_b, user=self.request.user)
print(a_to_b)
```

> [...] Note that if you are using an intermediate
>   model for a many-to-many relationship, some of the related manager’s
>   methods are disabled, so some of these examples won’t work with such
>   models.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Your error is explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: Thanks.    
Is there any point in making m2m fields in that case?    
I mean both `to_a` and `to_b` fields could simply be `ForeignKey` to AtoB model.

Comment: I would use a ManyToMany relation in case I had a connection between two classes that would require ObjectA related to `n` ObjectsB `AND` vice-versa. In a sense, a ManyToMany relation is just a ForeinKey to another table, but the level of abstraction provided by Django is higher and managing these objects is faster and less painful. You can, for example, bulk-add objects with `object_a.to_b_set.add(*QuerySet[])`. I would also add a `related_name` to these fields to make it easier. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add